# How to do the Ajax calls for multiple sets of contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Any advice on how to do the Ajax calls and stuff to pull in content for a set of components like those boxes on www.jwt.com home page at a time when you scroll down please? I am using jQuery Ajax.

Another related thread that I have posted can be found at:

[How do they populate the boxes on this website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379208/how-do-they-populate-the-boxes-on-this-website)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with the jQuery [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin. In particular look at the infinite scroll demo:

http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html

In terms of the AJAX calls, it looks like jwt.com uses a single AJAX call for each set of content (i.e. multiple content boxes are returned for each AJAX request/scroll down), so there's nothing really special in terms of the AJAX. The wizadry is in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger the AJAX when the user scrolls to the current limit of the page or limit of the content section you wish to append content to. Have the AJAX completion append the returned content to the end of the content section.